# doc.pageWindowRect and doc.media are undefined in Adobe Acrobat Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm using the Javascript API built-in to the Adobe Acrobat products, and trying to access the `doc.pageWindowRect` attribute.

I originally found that `doc.pageWindowRect` was undefined whenever I tried to access it, and through various posts on the AdobeUsers forum, found that I needed to activate the media extension first, by running something like `console.println(this.media);`

Normally this prints a result like: `[object DocMedia]`

However, on some computers used by our client, this just prints `undefined` instead. It seems that having `this.media` remain undefined means that `doc.pageWindowRect` will stay undefined too.

Does anyone know how to make sure `this.media` is defined, and thus enable `doc.pageWindowRect`? Or any other way of getting hold of the `doc.pageWindowRect` information?

I wondered if there might be a delay in activating the media extension (a suggestion I found online), and have tried repeatedly running code to display `this.media` and `doc.pageWindowRect` using `app.setInterval`, but even after waiting for a couple of minutes, they are still not defined.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For anyone interested in solving this problem, the author of this StackOverflow question has another thread with some more information on this problem that may be helpful over on Adobe's Support Community: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/doc-pagewindowrect-and-doc-media-are-undefined-in-acrobat-javascript/td-p/11469834

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that having this.media remain undefined means that
> doc.pageWindowRect will stay undefined too.
> Does anyone know how to [...] enable doc.pageWindowRect?

`pageWindowRect` belongs to the `multimedia.api` plugin. In Acrobat 9 and possibly other versions, this plugin is not by default loaded.

From what I can find in that scenario, one method for loading the multimedia.api plugin is to actually **have media** in the PDF file.

Default location for this plugin is: `%Program Files%\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\plug_ins\Multimedia.api`

This might not be the fixing answer, but I hope the suggestion gives some insight. Good luck!